# Error while working with two databases in Django: sqlite3.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: wagtailcore_page.draft_title

Tags: django, wagtail, django-migrations

I'm working on a Django Project with Wagtail which uses two databases. The first one is the standard sql lite database for all django models (called `db_tool.sqlite3`), the other one is also sql lite but for a wagtail integration (called `db.sqlite3`).

I wanted to migrate to the `db_tool.sqlite3` with the following command

```
python manage.py make migrations
python manage.py migrate --database db_tool
```

but now I get the following error message regarding wagtail, which I never got before.

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: wagtailcore_page.draft_title
```

First of all: I don't understand this, because I named the db_tool in particular and I wonder, why the wagtail integration raises an error when I try to migrate to db_tool.

Second: I see no particular field at my wagtail-pages called `draft_title` and I don't have any draft page at the moment.

Third: the error message also relates to a migration file of wagtail that can be found in the side-packages (see below). So maybe this is the root of the error, but I don't understand the correlation to the other error message, because since now it worked fine and I changed nothing exept of some content of my wagtail pages.

```
File "C:\Users\pubr\.conda\envs\iqps_web\lib\site-packages\wagtail\core\migrations\0001_squashed_0016_change_page_url_path_to_text_field.py", line 23, in initial_data 
root = Page.objects.create(
```

The wagtail version I use here is `wagtail 2.15.2` and I haven't updated it since I started the project...

Due to the fact, that my wagtail-database has the name of the default django-database, could it be possible, that I accidentally tried a migration which was ment for the `tool_db.sqlite3` without naming it in the `migrate`-command and caused this error by doing that?

So I would be very grateful if anyone knows, where the error comes from, or at least, what I could try out to fix it...

Kind regards and thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear to me if your database is currently broken or not. Hopefully not, but if it is, please take a back up of each before doing anything else.

This does sound like you might have been trying to operate in the wrong database. Do you have DATABASE_ROUTERS configured? I think that might help you prevent code from one app from getting introduced into the wrong database. The example in the Django docs is mostly focused on read replicas but should be adaptable to your situation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/multi-db/#an-example

If your databases are in an incorrect state, start by looking at the django_migrations file in each and then carefully pruning the messed up one until you get back to the separation you have been enforcing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have no routers implemented, but I will do so, when the issue is solved.

How do I recognize a messed up migration file? I looked them all up and at least I found no wrong database name in the dependencies...

Comment: Sorry, I misspoke when I said "looking at the django_migrations file in each". django_migrations is the table in each database listing which migrations have been applied. If you `select * from django_migrations` and look at the the last few lines, you should only see migrations from the apps managed in that database. If you see any wagtail migrations in your db_tool database or conversely normal django apps in what should be your wagtail database, then you will need to drop the tables that are in the wrong db and delete the corresponding lines from the django_migrations table.